# What is the reason for an "irreducible" (topological) space to be so called?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

A topological space $T$ is  "irreducible" if and only if no two non-empty open sets of $T$ are disjoint.

Such a space is also called "hyperconnected".

This is the definition given in 1978: Lynn Arthur Steen and J. Arthur Seebach, Jr.: Counterexamples in Topology (2nd ed.)

I personally prefer "hyperconnected" but have got shouted down on this subject by people who claim superior knowledge and authority. Hence the antithesis between this and an "ultraconnected" space, which is when no two non-empty **closed** sets are disjoint.

So having been told that "irreducible" is better than "hyperconnected", what I need to understand is: what is the reason for calling it "irreducible"?

It predicates the notion that somehow sets which *do* have disjoint non-empty open sets are thereby "reducible". But reducible to (and from) what?

In what way can an "irreducible" space not be "reduced"? What is "reduction" in this context anyway?

Wikipedia merely expands on this concept but does not explain the thinking.

Comment: While I do not know this for a fact, the information in the Wikipedia article strongly suggests that the term originated in algebraic geometry, where it has a more evident significance, and was carried over into topology via the Zariski topology. If that is the case, there’s no reason to expect it to have any very natural justification in a general topological setting; after all, it’s irrelevant in any setting in which, for instance, all spaces are assumed to be Hausdorff, and many topologists rarely leave such settings.

Comment: A difference between hyper- and ultraconnected is just as arbitrary, IMO.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Sorry, "as arbitrary" as what? Don't understand. Hyper- and ultraconnected are different concepts, so yes of course there's a difference, but why should it be arbitrary?

Comment: As arbitrary as calling one of them "irreducible". In an ultraconnected set we cannot write $X$ as a union of proper *open* subsets, so every open cover contains $X$, making $X$ trivially compact too. Hyperconnected spaces can be non-compact.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: But there is an aesthetically pleasing antithesis between the names "ultraconnected" and "hyperconnected" which makes the name "hyperconnected" more desirable as a name. Furthermore, the "connected" nature of the topology is a far more obvious property to focus on than any perceived non-obvious and convoluted notion of "reducibility" which is relevant really only to a limited subset of the field of topology. At base *all* mathematical terms are "arbitrary", but it's clear that some is more *relevant* than others, and here "hyperconnected" is more relevant than "irreducible".

Comment: Note that this terminology from Steen and Seebach is old-fashioned and almost never used in papers and other books. They often have non-standard conventions, it's not really meant as a text book or research text, more a convenient collection of examples to use in teaching.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Okay that sort of answers my question: it's a matter of fashion and accepted taste. Fair enough.

Comment: @PrimeMover: In this case your *æsthetically pleasing* is my *potentially confusingly similar*. This is a problem that does not arise with *paracompact*, *metacompact*, *orthocompact*, etc., because their Greek prefixes are fairly arbitrary anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is irreducible write $X=F \cup G$ where $F,G$ are closed and proper. Then De Morgan says $F^\complement \cap G^\complement = \emptyset$, and we have two non-empty (as $F$ and $G$ are proper subsets) disjoint open sets in $X$.

So another way to look at irreducible is to define it as "We cannot write $X$ as a union of two proper closed subsets", and writing a space as a union of two smaller closed sets can be seen as to "reduce" it, maybe. Maybe how irreducible elements in algebra cannot be written as a non-trivial (not using units) product . The terminology comes from the Zariski topology and algebraic geometry contexts, where there is a direct link to irreducible varieties.  We care about unions of closed sets because the closed sets are the "varieties", zero sets of polynomials, in the algebra connection.

Comment: Doesn't this use of "irreducible" conflict with the classic notion of "irreducible continuum"?

Comment: @bof "irreducible continuum" is *not* the same as "irreducible space that is a continuum" or a "continuum that is an irreducible space". It's indeed a separate notion. We cannot 'grammatically reduce' the definition of 'irreducible continuum', as it were. It's just history...